# Bult attribute edit in local AD

Tags: powershell, active-directory, windows-server

I'm trying to find a PowerShell script that updates the title attrubute in AD for a large number of users. I was hoping to find a script that imports the changes from a csv file and updates the atribute only for the users in the list. I found the below script but apparently it is working only for Azure AD, and I need it for the local AD. Perhaps someone more switche on than me can help me amend the below script.

```
#Import Active Directory module
Import-Module ActiveDirectory 

#Import CSV File to set variable for the user’s logon name + update data + delimiter
$Users = Import-CSV -Delimiter ";" -Path "c:\psscripts\users.csv"

#Using your code to filter AD Sam Accounts listed CSVData is listed with the information you wish to update

Foreach($user in $users){
    
    #Using your code to filter AD Sam Accounts Based on column samaccountname in the csv file
    Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$($user.samaccountname)'" | Set-ADUSer `
        -title $($User.Title)`
}
```

Comment: That will work on local AD too. What happened when you tried it?

Comment: Your code targets onprem AD.

Answer (score 0):

That code is fine, beyond some variable consistency and lack of checks, and does target local AD, though use of that deliminator would likely be unusual if you're just using a standard csv file.  If you have the data in an excel document with the column headers of "SamAccountName" (typically email addresses) and "Title", and then save the file as a csv, the below amended code should work for you.  Added logic to test for blank Title, as you can't assign a blank value to an attribute.

```
#Import Active Directory module
Import-Module ActiveDirectory 

#Import CSV File with AD SAM account and Title data from users.csv in the C:\psscripts directory of your computer
$Users = Import-CSV -Path "c:\psscripts\users.csv" | Where {$_}

#Filter AD Sam Accounts listed in CSV and update title for listed accounts

Foreach($user in $Users){
    #Check for value of $user.Title in case of null value
    If ($user.Title){
        #Filter AD Sam Accounts Based on column SamAccountName in the csv file and update the account Title field
        Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$($user.SamAccountName)'" | Set-ADUSer -Title $($user.Title)
    }
    else {
        #Filter AD Sam Accounts Based on column SamAccountName in the csv file and clear the account Title field
        Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$($user.SamAccountName)'" | Set-ADUSer -clear -Title
    }
}
```

I'd recommend testing it on a test user account or two before going whole hog on your actual list.  Goes without saying that you need to be logged into a PS session as a domain account with adequate privileges to make the changes to the accounts when running the script.  VS Studio Code is a good environment to work in, and you can launch the program as the elevated account (shift + right-click program icon, choose run as a different user) within your normal account environment, to sandbox the privileges to just what you're working on in VS Studio Code.

If you are trying to work in Azure AD, you'd need to add these lines and approve your account access request within Azure, depending on your tenant setup, to actually run the script successfully.  Depending on the tenant configuration, this may be required in a hybrid AD/Azure AD environment regardless of your intent to apply to local AD.

```
Connect-MgGraph -Scopes "User.ReadWrite.All", "Directory.ReadWrite.All"
Select-MgProfile -Name "beta"
```

Best regards, no warranties given or implied, please accept as answer if this works for you.